# How would I loop through this multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

What would be the most efficient way to loop through this multidemsional array? This array is much larger than the example given, and would contain all the visitors ip address who visit my site. Also I would only like to loop through the information contained in 'sc_data'.

```
 Array
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [status] => ok
    )

[sc_data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ip_addresss] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ip_address] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: `foreach($myArray['sc_data'] as $value) {...}`

Comment: @MarkBaker when I try to echo $value I get this error: Array to string conversion? Should I be echoing this differently?

Comment: Yes you should.... you should be echoing `$value['ip_address']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [most efficient](http://www.phpbench.com/) way to loop through an array is foreach

```
foreach($array['sc_data'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['ip_addresss'];
}
```